# Integral calculus question relating to particle motion

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, gamma-function

"A particle of mass m is attracted toward a fixed point 0 with a force inversely proportional to its instantaneous distance from 0. If the particle is released from rest, at distance L, from 0, find the time for it to reach 0."

Here's what I know:

$F=-{k \over x}$, where $k$ is a proportionality constant.

From basic physics I also know $F=ma=m{dv \over dt}$.

I equate the two: $-{k \over x}=m{dv \over dt}$.

I can simplify this expression with the following: ${dv \over dt} = {dx \over dt}{dv \over dx} = v{dv \over dx}$, which I then substitute into the previous expresion.

Through separable variables, followed by solving for the constant c, I can solve for $v$. As $v = {dx \over dt}$, I obtain the following:

$${dx \over dt} = \sqrt{-{2k \over m} ln\left({x \over L}\right)}$$

Here's where I am stumped. I believe the correct way forward to use separable variables again to obtain the following expression:

$${L*du \over \sqrt{- ln(u)}} = \sqrt{{2k \over m}} dt$$
where $u=\frac xL$. I have seen the left hand side being integrated from u=0 to u=1, using the Gamma Function. Using the Gamma Function is also in line with what we are using in calculus class right now and I believe is the right way forward. However, I am confused to as how exactly I can solve for $x$ as a function of $t$. Can anyone help? I've been stuck at this problem for a few hours now with no luck, and would be very grateful to anyone with a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $t = \sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{m}{2k}} L$.  Given what you've written above, you should be able to make the last connection.

Comment: After another day of working on this problem I am still unsure. I know integrating the left side from u=0 to u=1 will result in $L\sqrt\pi$. I don't understand how I can rationalize using a definite integral from 0 to 1 on the left side. I'm also unsure about how this will impact the right side. If you could please clear up any of my questions I would be grateful. Any help?

Comment: @MattGrenander:  You don't need $x$ as a function of $t$.  You only need to know how much time passes as $u$ goes from $0$ to $1$.  Since $\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{-\log u} = \sqrt{\pi}$ and $\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}t = \langle \text{the lapse you want} \rangle$, you have everything you need.  (In fact, you have the exact exchange factor for an infinitesimal change in time for an infinitesimal change in $u$.  Since you know the total finite change in $u$ you want, integrate to get the total finite change in $t$ that comes with it.)

Comment: Ah ok I see. The total finite change in u compared to the total finite change in t makes a lot of sense to me. Thank you very much! I have indeed gotten $L\sqrt{m\pi \over 2k}$ as my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation being $${dx \over dt} = \sqrt{-{2k \over m} ln\left({x \over L}\right)}$$ you can look at $${dt \over dx} =\frac{1} {\sqrt{-{2k \over m} ln\left({x \over L}\right)}}$$ and make the change of variable $$\sqrt{-\frac{2 k \log \left(\frac{x}{L}\right)}{m}}=y$$ that is to say $$x=L e^{-\frac{m y^2}{2 k}}$$ Then $${dt \over dy}=-\frac{L m e^{-\frac{m y^2}{2 k}}}{k}$$ and so $$t=-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} L \sqrt{m} \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{m} y}{\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{k}}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}+ C$$ If you replace $y$ by its definition , you should arrive to something like $$t(x)= c_1+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} L \sqrt{\log \left(\frac{x}{L}\right)}
   \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\log \left(\frac{x}{L}\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{-\frac{k \log
   \left(\frac{x}{L}\right)}{m}}}$$

I hope I did not make any mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your response Claude Leibovici! I'm in a first year calculus class, and we have definitely not been introduced to erfi(x)! I believe there is a simpler solution that my professor is looking for, although I have no doubt your solution works too! Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: @MattGrenander. I worked assuming that your equation was correct and I did not expect you to be in a first year calculus class. So, may be your basic equation is not the right one. Try to clarify and post. Cheers.